# Wxpython UltimateListCtrl not allowing row insert between existing rows

Tags: wxpython

I have been trying to convert an application that was using a wx.ListCtrl to the UltimateListCtrl as I need to do some header customisation.  In my code I populate the control and then later based on a selection I need to insert a new row between existing rows.  This works just fine on ListCtrl but on UltimateListCtrl it doesnt insert and shift the existing rows down.  Instead it adds it to the bottom.

I'm using Python 3.9.8 and wx 4.1.1.

Below is the UltimateListCtrl demo code from https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/02/wxpython-an-intro-to-the-ultimatelistctrl/.  I have just added my row insertion which doesnt behave as expected.  It creates rows 1, 2, 3 correctly.  I then try inserting a new row ahead of the last row but it overwrites the last row in a weird kind of way.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?  Also, the demo shows the window nice and correctly sized to fit the table.  When I run the demo it doesnt nicely fit and instead shows a horizontal scrollbar.  Tried to work that one out but so far have failed also without explicitly specifying a horizontal size.

```
import wx
from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ULC


class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        
        try:
            font = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)
            boldfont = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)
        except AttributeError:
            # wxPython 4 / Phoenix updated SystemSettings
            font = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)
            boldfont = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)

        boldfont.SetWeight(wx.BOLD)
        boldfont.SetPointSize(12)
        
        self.ultimateList = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(self, agwStyle = wx.LC_REPORT 
                                         | wx.LC_VRULES
                                         | wx.LC_HRULES)
        
        info = ULC.UltimateListItem()
        info._mask = wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT | wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE | wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT | ULC.ULC_MASK_CHECK
        info._image = []
        info._format = 0
        info._kind = 1
        info._text = "Artist Name"
        self.ultimateList.InsertColumnInfo(0, info)
    
        info = ULC.UltimateListItem()
        info._format = wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT
        info._mask = wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT | wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE | wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT | ULC.ULC_MASK_FONT
        info._image = []
        info._text = "Title"
        info._font = boldfont
        self.ultimateList.InsertColumnInfo(1, info)
        
        info = ULC.UltimateListItem()
        info._mask = wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT | wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE | wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT
        info._format = 0
        info._text = "Genre"
        info._font = font
        info._image = []
        self.ultimateList.InsertColumnInfo(2, info)
        
        self.ultimateList.InsertStringItem(0, "Newsboys")
        self.ultimateList.SetStringItem(0, 1, "Go")
        self.ultimateList.SetStringItem(0, 2, "Rock")
        
        self.ultimateList.InsertStringItem(1, "Puffy")
        self.ultimateList.SetStringItem(1, 1, "Bring It!")
        self.ultimateList.SetStringItem(1, 2, "Pop")
        
        self.ultimateList.InsertStringItem(2, "Family Force 5")
        self.ultimateList.SetStringItem(2, 1, "III")
        self.ultimateList.SetStringItem(2, 2, "Crunk")
        
        self.ultimateList.SetColumnWidth(0, 150)
        self.ultimateList.SetColumnWidth(1, 200)
        self.ultimateList.SetColumnWidth(2, 100)
        
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.ultimateList, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        


        # Now we try to insert a row between 1 and 2 (This works in a listctrl)
        self.ultimateList.InsertStringItem(2, "Bobby")
        self.ultimateList.SetStringItem(2, 1, "Go Go")
        self.ultimateList.SetStringItem(2, 2, "Weird")

        self.ultimateList.Refresh()
        wx.CallAfter(self.ultimateList.Refresh)
        self.Refresh()
        self.Layout()

########################################################################
class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="MvP UltimateListCtrl Demo")
        panel = TestPanel(self)
        self.Show()
    
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = TestFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: The control displays correctly for me (Unix) using the code from the example. It appears that InsertStringItem can only be used to *add* an item self.ultimateList.InsertStringItem(sys.maxsize, "Bobby") - presumably there is a sort mechanism (I've not looked too closely)

Comment: Yes I have tried in Linux and graphically its sized correctly.  Seems to be a Windows issue that I'll just have to work around.  I also have confirmed that the UltimateListCtrl indeed seems to work differently for insert.  I've worked around that also by storing the data in a list, inserting my new data into the list, then essentially redraw the control with new data.  Very inefficient.